# File Geodatabase SQL expression to get greatest 1 per group

Tags: arcgis-pro, sql, file-geodatabase, error-000358

I have a `RoadInsp` FC in a FGDB in ArcGIS Pro 2.6.8.

[image]

Using an SQL expression in the Select by Attributes tool, I want to select the greatest 1 per group.

In other words, for a given `ASSET_ID`, I want to select the inspection that has the latest `DATE_`. The selections in the screenshot reflect what I'm looking for.

Use case: [One-to-first joins: Control what related record is used](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/one-to-first-joins-control-what-related-record-is/idc-p/1237916/highlight/true#M22392)

---

I've written a SQL subquery that works as expected on a copy of the table in an Oracle 18c 10.7.1 EGDB:

```
objectid in (
    select      a.objectid
    from        roadinsp a
    inner join
       (select  asset_id, max(date_) as date_
       from     roadinsp
       group by asset_id) b
    on a.asset_id = b.asset_id and a.date_ = b.date_
    )
```

[image]

But when I try to use that same expression on the FGDB FC, I get an error:

[image]

```
ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).
```

---

**Question:**

Why do I get that error when I use the expression on the FGDB FC?

I've looked at the FGDB SQL syntax in the docs:

- [SQL for reporting and analysis on file geodatabases](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/help/data/geodatabases/manage-file-gdb/sql-reporting-and-anlysis-file-geodatabases.htm).
- [SQL reference for query expressions used in ArcGIS](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.6/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm#:%7E:text=or%20remove%20them.-,Subqueries,-A%20subquery%20is)

But as far as I can tell, all of the SQL syntax I've used is supported by the ArcGIS SQL dialect and FGDBs.

I've tested the same expression in ArcGIS Pro 3.0.3 and I get the error there too.

---

**Related:**

[Select greatest n per group using EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74735554/select-greatest-n-per-group-using-exists)

---

**Edit:**

One thing I didn’t consider:

If an asset has multiple rows with the same top date, then only one of those rows should be selected.

Comment: The only thing worse than Esri's SQL support with file geodatabases is their documentation of it.  The issue you are running into is related to the correlated subquery issue discussed on Esri Community:  [When EXISTS Doesn't: File Geodatabases and Correlated Subqueries](https://community.esri.com/t5/gis-blog/when-exists-doesn-t-file-geodatabases-and/ba-p/896574)

Comment: The SQL syntax you've used isn't supported, certainly by Pro 2.6, as the "Invalid expression" error indicates.  Keep in mind that SQL support isn't implemented by a full SQL Engine, so this isn't an exhaustively tested feature. Functionality is added as identified, but an inner join on a virtual table is not a SQL92 feature, and certainly a bridge too far for the current FGDB SQL implementation.

Comment: @Vince The [SQL for reporting and analysis on file geodatabases (2.6)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.6/help/data/geodatabases/manage-file-gdb/sql-reporting-and-anlysis-file-geodatabases.htm#:~:text=CROSS%20JOIN%20Table2%22-,Inner%20Join,-SQL) docs say that INNER JOIN is supported. And subqueries are supported as well: [SQL reference for query expressions used in ArcGIS (2.6)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.6/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm).

Comment: I would think that if Esri implemented the JOIN SQL syntax for reporting in FGDBs, then the syntax would work for SQL expressions too. I can't imagine there's logic in the FGDB engine that says, "JOIN only works for SQL that's for a report, but not for SQL that's for an expression". I don't think that'd be possible, so I have to assume that the reporting syntax works for SQL expressions too. I think my SQL should work.

Comment: I'd imagine it's the ***virtual table*** part that's the problem. Nonetheless, if you want to argue with the software on "Invalid expression", you might be waiting a while for it to apologize.

Comment: *”We have an open enhancement to improve our documentation on these differences and potential limitations like this when consuming SQL expressions, it is as follows:

ENH-000117745: Modify the documentation to provide detailed information about limited support for subqueries with File Geodatabase.”*

Comment: @User1974, that one isn't mine; however, I have logged numerous defects and enhancements over the years relating to SQL support in file geodatabases.  Looking back at bugs/enhancements I have logged with similar numbers, that specific ENH is likely from the end of 2018.  If that ENH hasn't been acted on by now, I would not expect it ever will.

Comment: @bixb0012 I tried a simpler EXISTS query: https://i.stack.imgur.com/241or.png. But it didn't work either. While it didn't error-out, it just selected all rows, which is incorrect. Whereas, in an Oracle EGDB, it selects the correct *greatest n per group* rows. Like you mentioned, that's happening because FGDB SQL expressions don't support correlated subqueries. Related post: [Select greatest n per group using EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74735554/select-greatest-n-per-group-using-exists).

Comment: Back in 2022, @Vince and I had wondered if virtual tables (aka derived tables or inline views?) were supported in FGDB SQL (ArcGIS Pro 2.6.8). That may or may not have been the case back then. But fast forward to now (2023) in Pro 3.2.1, and it looks like virtual tables ***are*** supported in FGDB SQL. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6ECE.png and [Selecting the most recent records based on unique values in another field](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/selecting-the-most-recent-records-based-on-unique/m-p/1369899/highlight/true#M77380).

Comment: For what it's worth, creating a *view on a view* does not seem to be possible. [Idea - FGDB database views — View that selects from an existing view](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/fgdb-database-views-view-that-selects-from-an/idi-p/1369894). Likewise, correlated subqueries are still unsupported.

Answer (score 1):

As you have worked out the SQL used in ArcGIS Pro is different to what is used in database systems, the key issue I think being this statement in the [help file](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm#)

> Because you are selecting columns as a whole, you cannot restrict the
> SELECT to return only some of the columns in the corresponding table
> because the SELECT * syntax is hard-coded. For this reason, keywords,
> such as DISTINCT, ORDER BY, and GROUP BY, cannot be used in an SQL
> expression in ArcGIS except when using subqueries.

So one has to come up with a work around; one such solution I have employed is this:

Run a summary stats tool, this allows you to group data, my demo is shown below:

[image: Sample]

Run the Add join, join by Asset_ID

[image: Add Join]

Now select where date is equal to max date
[image: Select]

Finally if required, remove join

This approach could be very easily turned into a model tool rather than you running the individual tools.  The alternative is to use cursors in a Python script.

Comment: Thanks! This was quite helpful. For my notes, this technique doesn't break ties if there are multiple rows per asset that have the same date.

Comment: Related: [Selecting the most recent records based on unique values in another field](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/selecting-the-most-recent-records-based-on-unique/m-p/1370014/highlight/true#M77391).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a FGDB database view that works on a similar table called species_records.

```
--species_records_latest_vw
select
    *
from
    species_records
inner join
    (select
        t_species,
        max(t_date) as t_date 
    from
        species_records 
    group by
        t_species) l
    on species_records.t_species = l.t_species 
       and species_records.t_date = l.t_date
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work as a SQL expression. I guess because it is a correlated subquery, just like my query in the original post above. However, a database view might be useful as an alternative.

Also, the query doesn't break ties when there are multiple rows per species with the same date.

Source: [Selecting the most recent records based on unique values in another field](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/selecting-the-most-recent-records-based-on-unique/m-p/1369899/highlight/true#M77380)